# Ubuntu:What is the right way to reinstall from source after package was installed via apt?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, debian, compilation

I have a python package previously installed via apt(by default).
Now I want to install new version and compile it manually from the sources with all the required modules.

How can I do that?
I suppose that

```
apt-get purge python
```

And then install from sources is not possible because python have lots of dependencies and will uninstall all of them in this case.

What is the right way to do that?

Comment: Might want to post this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). They'll probably have good advice.

Comment: You can just install the new version of python and replace the executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't replace your system's default Python interpreter.  It can break things which will be difficult to fix later.  Instead you probably want to use [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv).  You can then isolate any issues from your environment and have the added advantage of multiple Python installations which can tested independently.

Here is some worthwhile reading to get you started:

- http://www.lorenzogil.com/blog/2010/10/29/python-deployment-tips/
- http://mitchfournier.com/2010/06/25/getting-started-with-virtualenv-isolated-python-environments/
- http://www.clemesha.org/blog/modern-python-hacker-tools-virtualenv-fabric-pip

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt-get remove name-of-package
```

then

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

will remove the package and any dependencies that are no longer needed.

Comment: I think the point is that the OP doesn't want to remove all those dependencies. I don't know about more recent versions of Ubuntu, but in 8.04/8.10 most of Gnome used to depend on python, so `apt-get remove`-ing it was a good way to trash your system completely.

Comment: -1 You can clearly see the reason for not doing this if you read the whole question. Furthermore, if you have _any_ experience with Ubuntu you would know that there is whole boatload of python dependencies - removing python is a no-go.

Comment: If he installed the package via apt, then it's probably not something that GNOME depends on. Anything that GNOME depends on likely would have been installed *along with* GNOME.

Comment: He said it was "installed via apt(**by default**)" (emphasis mine) which makes it sound like the OP did not install this manually and is referring to the version that came with his Ubuntu install. The wording of the question also makes it sound like the OP already tried `apt` and saw that these dependencies were going to be removed.

Comment: @eldarerathis: If that's the case, he's mistaken in thinking apt would have installed python during system installation. Apt is just a front-end to dpkg. When someone talks about 'installing via apt', it's safe to assume they mean a non-essential library installed by the end-user.